# SQL Server 2014 All Administrator Accounts Disabled

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, access-control

I made the most ridiculous thing. I accidentally disabled both remote logins and database accesses for the Administrator accounts (including the one with Windows Authentication (Administrator account) and `sa` account on the production server! Please tell me a way that there is a way to access the server with administrator privileges! :(

Is it possible from an installation or some kind of command line etc?

Again, Administrator account IS disabled for SQL Server (but I have remote connection to server, the account itself is working...)

The Administrator account of the SERVER is `AAAAA\Administrator`, and the instance is `SOMETHING\SOME_INSTANCE`.

When I am trying to log in **from the remote desktop** (on the server itself) with the `AAAA\Administrator` account, it says its disabled:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging in using DAC account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start SQL Server in single-user mode.

> The documentation [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx) says:
>
> > Start the instance of SQL Server in single-user mode by using either the **-m** or **-f** options. Any member of the computer's local Administrators group can then connect to the instance of SQL Server as a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

See the page linked above for further considerations and step-by-step instructions.